# How do I make a single face of an object a particle emitter?

Tags: particles, faces

I have an object which has a particle emitter at the bottom. The entire bottom of it is currently the emitter but I would like to make the middle face the emitter. How would I go about doing this?[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can think of 2 ways that might work for you.

1. You can weight paint the bottom part that you want the particles to come from.

a. then under vertex groups > density choose the weight paint group you just made.

[image]

2. You can duplicate the face and hit "P" to seperate it from the mesh and just put the particle system on the new object you spererated. Then parent it to your main object (if it will be animated) and hide it with the emitter check box.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can make **Vertex Group** out of bottom face (create Group, select Face and hit Assign, without painting)...

[image: 1]

...and use it to control **Density** under **Particle System** > **Vertex Group**.

[image: 2]